# Добавить товар в корзину js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нужно добавить товар в корзину,если такой есть то увеличить count++. Не используя методы которые напрямую меняют массив.

```js
 basket: state.basket.find(
          item => (item.id === action.payload.id) 
          ?
          state.basket.concat({
            id: action.payload.id,
            count: item.count++,
          })
          : state.basket.concat({
            id: action.payload.id,
            count: 1,
          })
        ) ? state.basket : state.basket.concat({
          id: action.payload.id,
          count: 1,
        })
```

```js
basket: [
      {
        id: 12,
        count:1
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        count:1
      }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
basket: state.basket.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id ? item.count++ : null) 
      ? 
        [...state.basket] 
      :
        [...state.basket].concat(
          {
            id: action.payload.id,
            count: 1,
          }
        )
```